# How to get variables from fucntion.php to my plugin files

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions, variables, parameter

I have written a function in `functions.php` that gets variables from a contact form and sends the inputs (and some other info like IP and location..) to my email.

I am starting to work on my first plugin and I want to store the parameters in a new table on the database.

How do I get the parameters from `function.php` right after the user clicks on the **send** button of the `contact form`?

Answer (score 2):

There is three way to use `function.php` file variable into plugin file.

1. Using [global](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables). Make sure you globalize it first.

   `global $my_variable;
   echo $my_variable;`
2. I recommend is using WordPress built-in filter mechanism [add_filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/). You add the filter in your `functions.php` file and apply it where needed.

In `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'my_variable', 'return_my_variable' );
function return_my_variable( $arg = '' ) {
    return '111221122';
}
```

Now you can use in your plugin files:

```
echo apply_filters( 'my_variable', '' );
```

3. Use an action hook [add_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/)

In `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'my_variable', 'echo_my_variable' );
function echo_my_variable() {
    echo '888998899';
}
```

In your plugin files:

```
do_action( 'my_variable' );
```

Again, I recommend a filter because it can return a value. This is far more flexible than injecting echo calls in your plugin file. Whether you use an action hook or a filter is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Basic PHP:

**functions.php**:

```
function my_func() {
   //doing my staff
   $my_var = 'data'; //stored data after doing things
   return $my_var;
}
```

In plugin file:

```
//retrieved data from a function declared within a system
$got_data = my_func();

function another_func( $got_data ) {
   //doing staff with $got_data
}
```